# Performing HSV Threshholds in OpenCV for Java

Tags: java, opencv, hsv

I've done basic HSV threshholding in C++ OpenCV through the following

```
    inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
```

though I can't find anything similar in the Imgproc class (or any other class) in Java so could anyone point me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in Core, not Imgproc ;)

[inRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#inRange(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))